# delete element from cloud firestore array in swiftui

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: My list in firestore cloud]
I'm trying to remove an element (only one) from an array using arrayRemove() but all elements in my "note" array are removed

**Note struct**:

```
struct Notes: Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var nom: [String]
}
```

**Category struct**:

```
struct Categorys: Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var idDoc: String
    var note: Notes
}
```

**viewModel**:

```
class DataManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var note: [Notes] = []
    @Published var cat: [Categorys] = []

    func deleteFields2(cat: Categorys) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}

        let note = cat.note.nom
        db.collection("Users").document(userID).collection("Categorys").document(cat.idDoc).updateData([
            
            "note": FieldValue.arrayRemove(note)
        
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error updating document: \(err)")
                
            } else {
                print("Document successfully updated")
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove an item from the `note` array, you need to pass the exact value of that array **item** to `arrayRemove`. Your code passes an array to `arrayRemove`, so the code will remove any array **item** that is an array with the value you specify - which doesn't exist in the screenshots.

To remove the string *item* from the array, pass a string value to `arrayRemove`. For example:

```
db.collection("Users").document(userID).collection("Categorys").document(cat.idDoc).updateData([    
    "note": FieldValue.arrayRemove("cheese")
])
```